# Makefile: double substitution

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write a makefile for running a program with all possible settings of two variables taking values in the same set:

If there is a single variable, I can do:

```
LAMBDAS = 0.01 0.015 0.02 0.025 0.03 ..

RESULTS = $(patsubst %,results_%,$(LAMBDAS))

lambdas: $(RESULTS)

results_%:
     ./program_to_run --param1 $(patsubst results_%,%,$@) > $@
```

How can one extend this setup to handle two parameters, both taking values in LAMBDAS?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `foreach` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function):

```
ALPHA := a b c
NUMER := 1 2 3

RESULTS := $(foreach A, $(ALPHA),$(addprefix results_$(A), $(NUMER)))
```

Also note that there is a cleaner way to write your pattern rule:

```
results_%:
    ./program_to_run --param1 $* > $@
```

**EDIT:** If you want to separate the two parameters in the command, put a character between them when you construct `RESULTS`:

```
RESULTS := $(foreach A, $(ALPHA),$(addprefix results_$(A)_, $(NUMER)))
```

and then separate them within the command, which is a pain because like many things in Make, `patsubst` can't handle two wildcards at once.

This is a pretty good way, if the number of parameters is small:

```
results_%:
    @echo -p1 $(word 1, $(subst _, ,$*)) -p2 $(word 2, $(subst _, ,$*))
```

Comment: Thank you!  How can I address each parameter individually (to feed into --param1 and --param2 program options)?  ./program_to_run --param1 $* > $@ will lump the two parameters together.  Is patsubst the way to split?